# How to obtain the solution of the matrix in this Gauss Elimination

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A=[[1,1,8],[2,-1,1]]
def triangular(A):


    n = len(A) 
    for i in range(n):

        pivot = A[i][i]
        for j in range(i+1, n): 
            m = -A[j][i]/pivot
            for k in range(i, n+1): 
                A[j][k] += m*A[i][k]
def substitui(A):
    n = len(A) 
    x = n*[0] 
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):

        s = sum([A[i][j]*x[j]
        for j in range(i+1,n)])
        x[i] = (A[i][n] - s)/A[i][i]
        return x


def resolve(A):

    triangular(A)
    x = substitui(A)
    return x

print(resolve(A))
```

How to obtain the solution of this matrix A? I can not understand why it is going wrong, the solution is giving the values of x = [0,5] instead of x = [3,5]. Someone can give me a help with this problem?

Comment: Is `triangular(A)` doing what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a simple mistake. In `substitui`, the line `return x` should not be in the for-loop. You should unindent the line:

```
def substitui(A):
    n = len(A) 
    x = n*[0] 
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        s = sum([A[i][j]*x[j]
        for j in range(i+1,n)])
        x[i] = (A[i][n] - s)/A[i][i]
    return x  # like this
```